# Numpy operator does not function

Tags: python, numpy

First of all: I'm not sure if "operand" is the right word. I mean things like < > = in if/then/else.
(Edit: is is operator)

In the non function part of my code, I want to cut off a sine function and set values to the border of the cut:

```
from numpy import *
x = arange(-15, 15, 1)
y = 12.5*sin(2*pi/3.8*x+pi/2)

for i in y:
    print(y[i])
    if y[i] > 2.5:
        print(y[i])
        y[i] = 2.5
```

But python just doesn't do it always. What I get:

```
11.8227155213
11.8227155213
-8.46601964532
-5.02119280816
-8.46601964532
-10.9934218901
6.83685197653
6.83685197653
2.5
-10.9934218901
-8.46601964532
-5.02119280816
-8.46601964532
-10.9934218901
6.83685197653
6.83685197653
3.06856858926
3.06856858926
-5.02119280816
3.06856858926
3.06856858926
-5.02119280816
2.5
-10.9934218901
2.5
-8.46601964532
-5.02119280816
-10.9934218901
-10.9934218901
2.5
2.5
-10.9934218901
-8.46601964532
-5.02119280816
-8.46601964532
```

And for me 6.8368.. is greater than 2.5.
It continues if I calculate in smaller steps.
It is such a simple task, so where is my fault?

Comment: `>`, `<`, etc. are *operators*.  Operands are the "arguments" to these symbols.  For example, in the expression `2 > 1`, `>` is the operator while `2` and `1` are its operands.

Comment: I would recommend against using `from numpy import *` it can lead to names clashes and is probably importing a lot more than you are going to be using. `import numpy as np` seems to be the standard when working with numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using

```
for i in y:
```

but y contains a bunch of floats, so y[i] is probably not what you what you want

try

```
for i, _ in enumerate(y):
```

Another nice option is

```
y = minimum(y,2.5)
```

Comment: Ah.. I've seen this before.. That should solve it. But for knowledge: over what exactly iterates my function? Because for some values it works.